# Always call function only once when executing a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

i've got a class like this one below. I introduced the loghelper-function to create the necessary logging-elements.

All 3 functions (start, function1, function2) can be run via console with `rails r "Foo.start` seperately

I'm looking for an elegant solution to make sure @logger is created before executing any of the other three functions and is only created once.

```
class Foo
  def self.loghelper
    @logger = Logger.new(stdout)
  end

  def self.start
    self.loghelper
    self.function1
    self.function2
  end

  def self.function1
    self.loghelper
    @logger.info 'function1 foo'
  end

  def self.start
    self.loghelper
    @logger.info 'function2 bar'
  end
end
```

Comment: `@logger ||= Logger.new(stdout)` - now it doesn't matter, it'll only create the logger once.

Comment: There's some more stuff going on in the `loghelper`-function. Isn't there a more elegant solution?
Also what is this operator called you describe in your comment?

Comment: add on initialize method, transform the class methods to object methods and include singleton. This belongs to codereview, not stackoverflow.

Comment: This question belongs to code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's why you encapsulate instance variables

```
class Foo
  def self.logger
    @logger ||= begin
      [...]
      Logger.new(stdout)
    end
  end

  def self.start
    function1
    function2
  end

  def self.function1
    logger.info 'function1 foo'
  end

  def self.start
    logger.info 'function2 bar'
  end
end
```